# Replacing a View in Android onClick

Tags: android, button, view

I'm still kind of new to android. I'm writing a Tic Tac Toe game as a bit of practice. I'm trying to figure out how to replace views when I click a button. I have 9 buttons in a GridView. When a user clicks one, I want that to change to a non-clickable TextView and back to Button when a user click's the reset Button at the bottom of the screen.. I use a flag to keep track of player's turn so it'll know whether or not place an x or o. Is this even possible or am I stretching here?

Comment: The grid is made of Buttons or TextViews?

Comment: It's a grid of buttons

Answer (score 2):

You'll soon find that there are really not that many things that are stretching it for Android.

This is certainly possible. For each grid in your `GridView`, put in two elements - the `Button`, and the `TextView`. Change the visibility of each. In other words, you don't actually replace one with the other - you just hide one, and show the other.

So you'd have two items like this:

```
<Button ... android:visibility="invisible"/>
<TextView ... android:visibility="visibile"/>
```

And have both of these `match_parent`, so that they fill each grid and are basically both on top of each other.

To change the visibility in the code:

```
button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
textView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I'm trying to give you as little actual code as possible so you play with this and write it yourself, but this should definitely put you in the right direction. Let me know if you need more guidance though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it two different ways

1. You can put both a button and a textview in each grid and interchange their visibility when you click on the button. For this, you can set the button and textview properties from the xml layout and you dont have to do much programatically
2. You can use a button alone and just change the look by changing the background drawable at runtime. Then you can make it unclickable by disabling it or changing its focusable property to false

You can even use an imageview and just change the drawable src and disable it on user click. Android is quite flexible and this is not even a stretch. If you give a little more detail of the specifics you want to achieve, I could advise which solution will be best fit

Comment: How would you make a button "unclickable"?

Comment: Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
but.setClickable(false);

or 

but.setEnabled(false);